# Why is my Ramda dropRepeats function not working here?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

As you can see in my **[Ramda REPL link here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=R.dropRepeats%28%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%204%2C%202%2C%202%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20removeRepeats%20%3D%20tickers%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27removeRepeats%27%2Ctickers%29%3B%0A%20%20let%20cleaned%20%3D%20R.dropRepeats%28tickers%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27cleaned%27%2Ccleaned%29%3B%0A%20%20return%20R.dropRepeats%28tickers%29%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20tickers%20%3D%20%5B%27m%27%2C%20%27g%27%2C%20%27j%27%2C%20%27m%27%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20final%20%3D%20removeRepeats%28tickers%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27final%27%2C%20final%29%3B)**, I am expecting the `m` to be dropped from the final array. However it is still there?

[image]

Here is the doc on **[R.dropRepeats](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#dropRepeats)**

```
const removeRepeats = tickers => {
    console.log('removeRepeats',tickers);
    let cleaned = R.dropRepeats(tickers);
    console.log('cleaned',cleaned);
    return R.dropRepeats(tickers);
};

let tickers = ['m', 'g', 'j', 'm'];

let final = removeRepeats(tickers);

console.log('final', final);
```

Comment: the documentation says "Returns a new list without any consecutively repeating elements", those `m`s are not consecutive...

Comment: Lol well that is lame... hmm I guess I need to keep looking at another way to accomplish this with one of these frameworks.

Comment: @ewcz you want to post your answer? Btw I found a lodash solution here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#uniq

Comment: `array.filter((x, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) !== i);`

Comment: @LeonGaban if the comment helped then it has already served its purpose... :)

Comment: Ramda also have [unique](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`R.uniq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniq) may be the function you're after:

```
> R.uniq(['m', 'g', 'j', 'm'])
['m', 'g', 'j']
```